# Extract Specific Value from Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a work dilemma. I have some cells, too many to manual work, that have some combination of the below:

"grievance 01-11 filed 09/19/02"

I am hoping to get only the "01-11" or whatever combination of xx-xx from the cell. I have used =LEFT(R102,FIND("-",R102)-1), but it gives me everything before/after the dash.

Thank y'all for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SEARCH:

```
=MID(R102,SEARCH("??-??",R102),5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Truly saving me!

Comment: Please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.